# Splitting numbers into different columns using vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

This is my excel sheet:

[image]

I need to split numbers into beside columns without pull stops, I'm new to VBA can you please suggest me  how to write code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GKrY.png)

I want to get data into like this

Comment: Is there a reason why you tagged with Java?

Comment: I guess you are not new with google, however. Try googling “splitting numbers into different columns with vba” and get some inspiration to write some code. Then, if you get stuck with something, come back here with your code and its issues

Comment: Use `split()` on `.` to get an array of values, then populate each array into the adjacent columns.

Comment: And probably use `trim()` to get rid of the preceding spaces.

Comment: I have tried googling but it is showing about how to decimal numbers into whole numbers like that.. I Have tried text to columns also..

Comment: Can u please add some code here..

Comment: I have edited my question can u see again please

Comment: please consult: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - this will show you how stackoverflow works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this, I think.

```
Sub SplitStuff()
'Update 20140318
Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In InputRng
    xValue = Rng.Value
    xRow = Rng.Row
    For i = 1 To VBA.Len(xValue)
        OutRng.Cells(xRow, i).Value = VBA.Mid(xValue, i, 1)
    Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Or use this function; fill down and fill right.

```
=MID($A1, COLUMNS($A$1:A$1), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Macro Recording with text to columns I got the below code. You can customize as you wish. Hope it will useful to you.

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :=".", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
    1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim Rng As Range, B As Range
    Dim x As Integer, H As Integer

```
Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B1:B220")

x = 1
For Each c In Rng
    For y = 1 To Len(c.Value)
        Rng(c.Row, x) = Mid(c.Value, y, 1)
        x = x + 1
    Next y
    x = 2
Next c
```

This works for me..
Thank you!!